# Are jQuery i18n plugins necessary?

Tags: jquery, internationalization

Doing that instead of using a i18n plugin:

A general js file:

```
$.getJSON("lang.json", function(i18n){
    //some codes which irrelevant with i18n
    $("p").text(i18n.sometext);
    //some codes which irrelevant with i18n
});
```

Will it decrease performance? Should I use a i18n plugin?

Comment: There’s a nice tutorial here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3

Answer (score 1):

You should almost always use a plugin since there are numerous factors and capabilities to consider such as:
- language file management and loading
- DOM traversal and manipulation
- Performance impact at runtime

Assuming they're well written and maintained, plugins tend to address precisely these kind of issues.

Finally, if you don't find a feature you're looking for, try requesting it with the project maintainers or add it yourself and contribute it back.

Here are the ones I'd recommend:
- https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n
- http://i18next.com/

Comment: There’s a nice tutorial here: https://dev.to/adrai/the-progressive-guide-to-jquery-internationalization-i18n-using-i18next-3dc3